# How do I edit/fix this class?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, memory-leaks, destructor

I wanted to practice building classes. I learned in my class that having leaked memory is never good, When I call this class, am I creating an object and do I need to add a delete function in my destructor to avoid leaks? Thank you!!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class Quadratic
{
public:
    Quadratic(int ia, int ib, int ic);
    int evaluate(int x);

private:
    int a, b, c;
};

Quadratic::Quadratic(int ia, int ib, int ic)
{
    a = ia;
    b = ib;
    c = ic;
}

int Quadratic::evaluate(int x) 
{
    int answer = a * (x * x) + b * x + c;
    return answer;
}

Quadratic::~Quadratic()     // ctrl + k + c to comment out large section of code. 
{
    cout << "Goodbye" << endl;
}

void main()
{
    int list[3] = { 2,3,4 };
    int* p1 = &list[0];
    int* p2 = &list[1]; 
    int* p3 = &list[2];

    // calling a class looks like this
    Quadratic* problem = new Quadratic(2, 3, 4);
    int answer = problem->evaluate(0);
    cout << answer << endl;

}
```

Comment: add "delete problem" to release memory

Comment: You define `Quadratic::~Quadratic` destructor, but you haven't actually declared it in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see three problems with your code, first of all the destructor: In the destructor you should free any dynamic items created in this case you have none which is good, also you should set your variables to their default value. Reset values for a, b, and c. Secondly the call problem->evaluate shouldn't work. I would not declare Quadratic* name, just do Quadratic name. Replace problem->evalute with problem.evalute. Finally it is usually an industry convention to seperate your header and implementation files with the exception of templates.

Comment: yes! i was going to practice separating the class into a header next! Thank you for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not provide garbage collection, so yes, you do need to delete memory manually.

You can do this by typing

`delete problem;`

after you are done using it.

Comment: if i added delete problem, it would be in the main, is there a way to add it to the destructor?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add destructor to your class functions:

```
~Quadratic();
```

Additionally, you need to add

```
delete problem;
```

to your main function for relase the occupied memory by your pointer.

Comment: if i added delete problem, it would be in the main, is there a way to add it to the destructor?

Comment: Yes "delete problem;" should be in the main function and you should call it after you are done using the pointer. The definition of the destructor should be in the class where you define constructor and "evaluate" function.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are saying delete problem..... That is exactly why you do not create a pointer for Quadratic..... Get rid of the * symbol after Quadratic and you do not need to delete it later. Generally we don't use * symbol after object, there are exceptions through.... Been coding in c++ for 3 years now and I rarely see people use the * after the object in a program this size..... * means dynamic memory allocation.... Which you probably do not want to do...

thanks,
Yun Fei Chen

Comment: I fixed my code according to how you said and it worked perfectly! Thank you! So because I do not create a pointer, I noticed that the destructor was called even tho I didn't explicitly delete it. Is that because the pointer is destroyed immediately?

Comment: I think you need to understand the difference between static and dynamic, if you do not create a pointer it is pass by value, so in other words once the program is done, everything is gone, just like declaring a value in your local functions. If you use a pointer however, it stays in the heap which is why you would get memory loss. It is dynamic allocated. The destructor is always called......

Comment: You do need the * symbol for much larger classes but that is not until much later, where you have multiple objects and the relationship is not always clear.... For example multiway trees and graphs, but at this point it will be a while before you start dealing with multiway trees or graphs or any thing like it.